# What does it mean to play an interval "below"?

Tags: intervals

If someone tells me to play a D power chord a fifth "below", what am I to play and why?

Comment: If you are playing an A power chord with the root on the 12th fret of the A string or 7th string of the D string they want you to go down one fifth lower to the 5th string of the A string or 0th fret of the D string. If you are playing any other chord, it makes no sense and you should ask them what they mean.

Comment: If you play an E power chord off the D string, playing it with "the fifth below" will result in an inverted power chord [like this](http://www.chorderator.com/designer?tuning=EADGBE&frets=+2+2+4++) (as opposed to playing it without the fifth below, [like this](http://www.chorderator.com/designer?tuning=EADGBE&frets=++2+4++)).

Answer (score 2):

A power 'chord' consists of a root note, the note a P5 above it, and sometimes the note an octave above that root. As in D - A - (D).

To play 'a fifth below' would be to use the same notes, but as an *inversion*. Probably called a second inversion, but who knows, as there's no 3rd there,(and with only two notes to play with, could there ever be anything more than a 1st inversion..?) but using theory, that inversion will have 5 underneath. So the notes would be A lower than the next D.

Comment: Doesn't the inversion have a 4th below then? We're not talking about the 5th of the power chord. He's asking about the interval. So the interval of an inverted power chord would be a 4th below the root. I think, the sentence above would only make sense, if you played an A power chord before and add that to the end of the sentence. "Play a D power chord (a fifth below A)"

Comment: @Andy I think you're right; in a power chord, I think the person originally talking to OP was referring to playing _the_ fifth below, ie playing _a_ fourth below. Actually playing a fifth below the root note would result in a sus chord, not a power chord.

Answer (score 0):

> What does it mean to play an interval “below”?

You need the specific interval and the reference tone. Like: *play a perfect fifth below `A`*. It's not clear if the intention is to play both tones together, but I would expect that. Someone could say *I'll play this riff* and then add *you play it an octave below to double the part*.

> ...If someone tells me to play a D power chord a fifth "below"

...they are being vague, or just redundant.

Actually, they don't need to make any reference to what that chord is *below*. They just need to say what octave or, if this is guitar, what string to play it on. Saying *play a D power chord a fifth below*, means first of all it would need to be below an `A` to make sense and then you would play a `D` with an `A` above it. But you would do the same thing if simply told play a D power chord. You would still play a `D` with an `A` above.

If they meant for you to play `A` below the `D`, you could probably just call that an *inverted power chord*. Play *power chords in fourths* would seem to convey the same thing.

> ...play a D power chord [with the] fifth "below" [the root]

...something like that fills in the blanks.